# Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Currently trying to use the Stanford Arabic segmenter and am getting

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter

I've made sure that the folder containing the .jar files are in the classpath, and even individually added the .jar files to the path as a last-ditch effort but am still getting this error.

I'm running the command

java -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.international.arabic.process.ArabicSegmenter -loadClassifier data/arabic-segmenter-atb+bn+arztrain.ser.gz -textFile arabic_poems.txt > my_arabic_file.txt.segmented

as from the README where arabic_poems.txt is the file containing the utf-8 coded Arabic text and where my_arabic_file.txt.segmented is the target file

(even tried just using my_arabic_file.txt as a target as I was unsure about the .segmented, but still the same error)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably you don't have your `CLASSPATH` configured correctly.  What it the output of `echo $CLASSPATH` ?

Comment: Are you running this on the command line, in an IDE ?  If you are getting a class not found error it's almost always something is wrong with your CLASSPATH or you are lacking the proper jars.